# nodejs,Express and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, passwords

I am new with Node js.I create a application with express framework and mysql database.i did add user and login.That's working fine but now am trying to reset my password with one time url.please help me.

Comment: Show what you have tried to initiate help.

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't contains any code snippets, any specific logical flow. If you are able to post some code, the you will be getting more accurate answer. Anyway I will try to provide a broad logic.
From your question, I understood that you know how to use expressjs routing, connecting to mysql from expressjs etc. 
So for resetting password, you need to send a link with a unique token to the user when user clicks on a forgot password/reset password link. Store this tocken in a separate mysql table with a created time stamp. When user clicks this url which send to his emailid, check with the token entry in db table and make sure it is not expired, and show the user a reset password interface. After resetting, remove the token stored in the db table.